# Handwritten Character Recognition differentiating between forward slash "/" and 1?

Tags: neural-network

Does anyone have any suggestions for helping a neural network differentiate between the forward slash character "/" and the number one? I'm using the MINST dataset and a lot of the 1's are sidewise and look a lot like the forward slash character, making a lot of my forward slashes become categorized as 1's instead of /'s.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add more "/" images and "1" images to your data. You can also add data augmentation like slight rotation.

To get more accuracy in classifying between "/" and "1", you can train a binary CNN classifier as your secondary classifier just to do this job. Call this classifier when your primary model predicts either "/" or "1".

More importantly, if you, as a human, are not able to classify between "/" and "1", then it's better not to expect a CNN to do the classification.